# call veriable and object from function to another

Tags: php, function, pdo

I has this function to get root of user and its work .

```
   public function getRootUser()
{
    $query = "SELECT id, nameOfPerson, parent FROM person WHERE parent is null";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute();
    echo '<ul id ="family">';
    while($family = $statment->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

        echo '<li>'. $family->nameOfPerson;
      }
}
```

And i have this function to get the child of the root , but its not work why?

```
public function getChildOfParentUser($parentId)
{

        $parentId = $family->id;
        $query1 = "SELECT id, nameOfPerson, parent FROM person WHERE id = $parentId";
        $statment1 = $this->db->prepare($query1);
        $statment1->bindValue('id', $family->id);
        $statment1->execute();
        if($statment1->rowCount() > 0){
        echo '<ul>';
        while($family2 = $statment1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            echo '<li>' . $family2->nameOfPerson . '</li>';
        }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
            echo '</li>';

            echo '</ul>';
}
```

he give this notice

```
Notice: Undefined variable: family in /var/www/html/Family.php on line 59

Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in /var/www/html/Family.php on line 59

Notice: Undefined variable: family in /var/www/html/Family.php on line 62

Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in /var/www/html/Family.php on line 62
```

this is some data from my table

```
id  nameOfPerson    parent
3   John             NULL
4   Michel            3
5   Husam             4
6   Khalaf            5
7   Mark              5
----------------------------
```

Comment: This two function have some relation then only you will get access to a private member or else use **GLOBAL** keyword to access variable globally like in `getChildOfParentUser($parentId){ GLOBAL $family;}`

Comment: @Ganesh i try it he give me this notice 
Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in /var/www/html/Family.php on line 59

Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in /var/www/html/Family.php on line 62

Comment: Kindly post Full code of `Family.php` file or use **pastebin**

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi https://pastebin.com/nf5y8Aa2

Comment: @husamalmasri kindly can you provide the sample data of person table

Comment: I update my post check it please

Comment: how ever i am checking but don't you think your `Family` class missing the `public  $db;` property which you are using in the `Family` constructor.

Comment: @husamalmasri is that your desired result https://ibb.co/bKTCTJ

Comment: @deceze kindly remove it from the duplicate question as i think it look like but it is not .

Comment: @Er. How's it _not_ a duplicate? Clarify the question to clearly distinguish it from the existing duplicates.

Comment: As i think user want to short out the function `public function getChildOfParentUser($parentId)` is not working. so in my opinion user having some logical errors here. And i think it wont be good to change question by my own i think user have to do it his own.  
@deceze 
@husamalmasri

Comment: @Er. The immediate problem is variable scope. The _bigger_ problem is that there's no apparent relationship between those two functions, and we can't even really suggest the best solution without knowing how they are related. So at best I'd close this as "unclear" otherwise.

Comment: But we are here to help not to close the question. I think .Rest is on you.